# Android what exactly does mediaplayer error 1, -107 mean

Tags: android, media-player, extra

Today I got much this error message from MediaPlayer :

```
06-03 17:44:02.707: E/MediaPlayer(20140): error (1, -107)
```

Only I can found is "-1007"'s error code describe, but that's not what I want.

And there is no anything about -107 I can find in API document.

What exactly the error code extra="-107" mean ?

Please help me to found out, thank you~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also been receiving this error message and tried sifting through the Android source code to no avail.

The only thing I can find on Google is [this page](http://blog.csdn.net/ameyume/article/details/9202985) (in Chinese) which seems to think it is related to a Network Link Error.

Comment: Your link is useful, I can read about 80% simplified chinese word, thanks :-)   (We're using traditional chinese word)

Comment: No problem, some of us aren't as talented and had to use Google Translate ;) It does match up with a few searches I did around the Android source code, which ended in the HTTP client class inside the connect() method. I'm pretty sure it just a default fallback code for when the connection fails for any reason.